# storing class names in database anti-pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, anti-patterns

For a requirement, I am thinking of storing the names of the classes that wil be instantiated for different customer type in database. Eg: A table with column for customer type like 1,2 etc, and another column to store the name of the class that will handle the customer.

All these classes will implement a common interface and will,be instantiated runtime based on type of customer coming in. The idea is to not write code when a new customer is added. A new class will be created and it will be entered in the db.

I am not sure if this is anti pattern since it hides the classes that are handling the business logic in db.

Please give your suggestions.

Comment: +1 to the accepted answer, but what value does a database add over an IoC container that would do more of the work for you?

Comment: Database table that I am planning to use will also have enable and disable flag to turn on and off processing of customers. Apart from this if db holds a new type of customer I don't have to add if or case to process that new type. That is the idea. If you have any better way that is configurable please do share.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't appear to be any different than storing the names of the implementation classes in a config file and then having [an IoC container resolve services based on that config](http://docs.castleproject.org/Default.aspx?Page=XML-Registration-Reference&NS=Windsor&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1), which is acceptable practice.

Therefore, my answer would be: no it's not an anti-pattern.